# DataTables warning: table id=myDatatable - Ajax error

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc, database

I am trying to make a simple MVC website, but my database is not showing. I tried to downgrade my jQuery version

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var oTable = $('#myDatatable').DataTable({
    "ajax": {
      "url": 'home/GetOrders',
      "type": "get",
      "datatype": "json"
    },
    "columns": [{
      "data": "FirstName",
      "autoWidth": true
    }, {
      "data": "LastName",
      "autoWidth": true
    }, {
      "data": "FuelType",
      "autoWidth": true
    }, {
      "data": "Quantity",
      "autoWidth": true
    }, {
      "data": "City",
      "autoWidth": true
    }, {
      "data": "Address",
      "autoWidth": true
    }]
  })
```

Comment: If there's a problem with the AJAX request then the issue is in your `home/GetOrders` endpoint, not the JS logic. You need to check the response text of the request in dev tools to diagnose the problem, then fix your MVC action

Comment: Can you also include the code for `GetOrders`?

Comment: You need follow server side https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side